# Full path disclosure on my applications.css

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My application is doing some kind of logging and exposing my computer folders and username in application.css 
I have the stylesheet tag on my application.html.erb

```
layouts/application.html.erb
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>
```

It renders a link like a normal rails applications would something along the lines of

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" 
href="/assets/application.self-
80b79e181044a0c9a308926720613f77d9222f04fe80f2a18ad8b83fa3ca7e3d.css?
body=1" />
```

However if a follow the link the document reveals sensitive information about my computer

```
/*!
 * Bootstrap v4.0.0 (https://getbootstrap.com)
 * Copyright 2011-2018 The Bootstrap Authors
 * Copyright 2011-2018 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
 */
/* line 1, /Users/XXXXX/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootstrap-4.0.0/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_root.scss */
:root {
  --blue: #007bff;
  }

/* line 21, /Users/XXXX/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootstrap-4.0.0/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_reboot.scss */
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* line 27, /Users/XXXXX/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootstrap-4.0.0/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_reboot.scss */
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.15;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -ms-overflow-style: scrollbar;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

What could be causing this problem?

**Edit:** I'm using rails 5.1, once the app is deployed and running on production mode, it doesn't show the path of the production server it still disclosures my computer folders.

application.scss

```
@import "pulse/variables";
//Custom bootstrap variables must be set or imported *before* bootstrap.
@import "bootstrap";
@import "pulse/bootswatch";
@import "bootstrap-select/bootstrap-select";
```

Comment: Can you show application stylesheet?

Comment: done, it's a basic scss file with some imports

Answer (score 0):

Put your bootstrap stylesheet to `/lib/assets/stylesheets` then try to require with pipeline:

**application.scss**

```
//= require pulse/variables
//= require bootstrap
//= require pulse/bootswatch
//= require bootstrap-select/bootstrap-select
```

Comment: What I did was to delete the public assets folder rm -r /public/assets then ran rake tmp:clear and now it's working normally not leaking information, thanks for your help

Comment: @AntonioA In production, rails precompiles these files again. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#how-to-use-the-asset-pipeline